# Collision Detection If Raycast Source Is inside A Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to cast a ray from inside source to Sphere.
my main camera position (0,0,0)
Sphere position (0,0,0) radius : 300
I want to know hit.position and hit.collider.gameobject
I am trying this below tutorial.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/129715/collision-detection-if-raycast-source-is-inside-a.html

Even if I tried tutorial, I can not see desirable result from console window.
(no Debug.Log result in my console window)
What should I have to do?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EyeTrackingPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sphereRadius = 300; // position(0,0,0) radius 300
    public GameObject screen3D; // sphere

    public void Update()
    {
        Camera cam = Camera.main; // position(0,0,0)
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(cam.transform.position,cam.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * sphereRadius );
        ray.direction = -ray.direction;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit)&&hit.collider.gameObject.Equals(screen3D))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.point);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Raycast in unity has to be conform to these things; Use a worldpoint from where the ray should originate. Use a direction for that ray. And u need to specifiy in which layer it is supposed to check. On top of that only objects with colliders can be hit, even if the gameobject is in the correct layer but doesn't have a active collider nothing will happen. Example ;

```
    {
     RaycastHit hit = Physics.Raycast(start, direction, 1000f, 1<<10);
    }
```

The information of a successful raycast is saved in a RaycastHit;
The 1000f is a float value that limits the range of the raycast That way u can control how far it looks for an object.

If u do not specify the layermask in the raycast it will return the first object hit with any kind of active collider regardless in which layer it is.

Comment: He's not asking how to use Raycast. He's asking what happens when you throw a raycast FROM WITHIN a collider.

Answer (score 1):

Raycasts from inside colliders do NOT generate collisions.

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, 100))
        Debug.Log("HIT");
```

"Hit" will never be written in console if a sphere is around the 0,0,0 world origin. When you move the sphere out , over and away from the origin, you will see it printed.

Those are impact in backfaces. You can enable it, though, enabling the checkbox in the Physics settings. See the documentation on this parameter on c# too: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-queriesHitBackfaces.html